# Почему враги - заклятые?

Tags: фразеология

Все мы знаем выражение "заклятые враги" - то есть, речь о крайней степени вражды.
Но интересно было бы узнать, о каком заклятии идет речь? Или же это просто фигуральное выражение?
Заранее спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ЗАКЛЯТЫЙ, 1. Такой, на который наложено заклятие (1 зн.). З. клад. З-ая пещера. З. дом.
2.Непримиримый, вечный (о враге, противнике). Это переносное значение.

Заклинать - это  стремиться воздействовать на кого-, что-л., подчинить кого-, что-л. силой заклинаний. З. клад. З. мечи.

Если сравнить слова "проклятый и заклятый", то значение приставок таково: приставка ПРО - через предмет проходит воздействие (проклятие); приставка ЗА - предмет получает завершенное, окончательное,  вечное воздействие (заклятие).

Answer (score 1):

Второе значение у слова "заклятый" – непримиримый, вечный. И плясать надо, думаю, от второго слова (вечный). Вот так "заколдовали", что враг стал вечным, а раз враг – то, естественно, непримиримый.

Answer (score 1):

От слова "клятва" в значении «такой, против которого дали клятву бороться до конца». (Этимологический словарь русского языка).

Comment: Почему тогда не бывает "заклятых друзей", которые тоже могут дать клятву? ))

Comment: @Niemand и как вы себе это представляете? "Клянусь, что буду вечно твоим другом?" Это же феерический бред. Друзья они априори дружат без всяких клятв. Другое дело, когда человек клянётся отомстить: масса примеров в художественных произведениях, но найдёте ли вы столько же о "клянусь с тобой дружить"? Разумеется нет.

Comment: В вечной дружбе клянутся нередко. Во всяком случае, так было до того момента, как мы перешли на товарно-денежные отношения, то есть, до развала  СССР.

Answer (score 1):

http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_bible/1562/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5

В библейской энциклопедии Заклятие (евр. херем) - отлучение кого-либо от мира человеч. существования и передача его в распоряжение Бога. Как правило, существо или предмет, предаваемые  заклятию, уничтожались. Именно поэтому они считались священными. Евр. харам означает "предавать уничтожению, уничтожать", эфиоп. харама - "отлучать от мирского общества" (ср. также араб. харем).

В ВЕТХОМ ЗАВЕТЕ это понятие употребляется применит. к войнам и обозначает полное уничтожение городов, людей, животных и вещей (Чис 21:2 и след.; Втор 13:12-18; Нав 10:28-40; Суд 1:17; 21:11 и след.; 1Цар 15:3; 3Цар20:42).

Заклятие. см. Анафема (Нав. гл. 6, 7). Как видно из означенной цитаты, города разрушенного и преданного заклятию не должно было восстановлять; он должен был оставаться в развалинах. Пример сего представляет город Иерихон при Иисусе Навине.

Отсюда заклятый враг - враг навсегда, необратимо,  отлучённый от людей и осуждённый на смерть.

Comment: Не уничтожить, а наложить печать и приковать на цепь, сделать рабом лампы, запечатать, замуровать. Отсюда Джинны, Сатана, Саурон, Кащей Безсмертный.

Comment: Если уж проводить параллели с христианством и Толкиеном, то Саурон - это антихрист, а то, что Вы сказали, - это Моргот.

Answer (score 1):

Всё очень просто и очень сложно. Заклятый - меченый: изувеченный - недобитый, выживший (враг). Как будто заговорённый. Имеющий характерные шрамы (татуировки) (вырезанные) на теле. Заклятьем запечатан и Кувшин, в котором спал Джинн. А само заклятье отчеканенная на корпусе кувшина вязь букв.